# C# Is it possible to create optional generic type constraints

Tags: c#, generics, type-constraints

I think I know the answer to this but I have the need to specify that a generic method can take a type based on two optional constraints. That being that T can be either one type or another.

```
public WebPage Click<T>(Func<WebPage> predicate) where T : LinkBase || FieldBase, new()
{
    WebDriver.FindElement(new T().LinkPath).Click();
    WebDriver.Wait();
    return predicate.Invoke();
}
```

I know that there is no such syntax currently, but is there a way to solve this without duplicating the method to constrain on both types? If not, is this in the realms of possibility for a future version of the language?

Comment: Whoever voted to close, how on earth is this not a real question?

Comment: Note: duplicating the method as you suggest would also be insufficient. Constraints are not part of the signature, so they would have to differ in more than just that. The name, the arguments, etc.; there must be another variance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're right, there's no way to pass in multiple types into a generic method.

Do you have control over both types? Can you make them each implement the same interface or abstract class?

Comment: That's correct. Essentially they both have a LinkPath property and it's questionable whether then should share this abstraction. However, the question in general still stands where this is not the case.

Comment: Sure, I understand abstraction may be questionable, but if it's just the one property, then having an interface here should do the trick, and is fine by design practices.

Otherwise, there's not a way for a generic method to take in multiple types, because the compiler needs to know exactly what properties could be passed in, and it can't just infer that two different types have the same common property

Answer (score 6):

Doing this does not make sense if `LinkBase` and `FieldBase` do not have a common base or implement a common interface. And if they do, then you can simply use that one as the constraint.

I 'm saying it does not make sense because the very reason of using type constraints is to make sure that the actual generic type parameter used supports a known public interface (otherwise, you could have just made the whole thing to be non-generic and use `object`). But if you have a hypothetical "or" constraint, how would the compiler be able to make sure that the code you write inside the generic will actually be meaningful for the type parameter that ends up being specified?

Comment: As per the answer to Mike, this may pose a question as to the design. They do not have a common base between them, however the method does require that they have the same property, so the compiler is/could be aware that the property exists/can exist. Yes I could pass the LinkPath in, but I don't want to.

Comment: @Ryan - If *all* you need is the LinkPath, then you *should* consider only passing that in. The principle of least knowledge would be applicable.

Comment: @RyanTomlinson: The dynamic nature of generics (as opposed to C++ templates, where the compiler will do exactly what you suggest) means that the compiler needs to generate code that works as-is in both cases. As you probably already know, in C# your only option for doing this is reflection. But reflection loses type safety while generics are intended to offer type safety, so it's not an option to have the compiler emit code that reflects on the objects (it would also have other major drawbacks). That doesn't leave any workable solution.

Comment: @RyanTomlinson: However, you can simply have your classes implement the same interface and expose `LinkPath` through that interface. Wouldn't that be a satisfactory workaround?

Comment: @Jon - Yes that's what I've currently gone with. I understand the compiler needs to know the type for generic constraints and reflection isn't exactly what I meant. Like I said, I'm pretty sure it would be impossible for the language to be capable of but I just wanted to be sure.

Comment: @Anythony - The problem with that is that, by design, I want only the Field or Link base to know of its LinkPath. This shouldn't be passed in to the method, as only the objects themselves should hold that knowledge.

Comment: @Ryan, consider what your words mean. Should the method even be aware of `.LinkPath`? Should that property even be part of the public API? By your code, you clearly want that knowledge to be shared. It's just a matter of when you choose to take advantage of it.

Comment: Apologies, by "passed in to the method" I meant passed in directly as a string. I want this to be self contained in a link object where other properties and methods exist on that page element.

Answer (score 2):

One option for such problems is to apply the adapter pattern to your classes. In this case, they share the same properties, but not the same interface. (This is most useful if you do not control the source or it does not otherwise make sense for them to actually share an interface in normal scenarios.)

```
interface ILinkablePath
{
    string LinkPath { get; }
}

class LinkBaseAdapter : ILinkablePath 
{
    private LinkBase linkBase;

    public LinkBaseAdapter(LinkBase linkBase) 
    {
        this.linkBase = linkBase;
    }

    public string LinkPath { get { return this.linkBase.LinkPath; } }
}
```

You can write an adapter for each class you want to support. If they do not share a common interface, and possibly do not even share common methods or properties (in name, if not in execution), then you can use this technique when you wish to use the classes in the same way.

When you've done this, you are able to cleanly work with the adapting interface in your methods.

Otherwise, for your specific problem here, you can simply create different methods for each type you wish to support, or (if you're just working with the single property and not the rest of the object), just pass in the value of the property you want to use rather than the entire object itself.